# MPMoviePlayerController issue

Tags: ipad, ios4, mpmoviewcontroller

In our iPad app, a video stream is playing in a player view. The player view has a button to go to a new view (I push the new view in the navigation controller when user clicks this button). The new view has a back button to go back to the player view.

The requirement is that the video should continue to play even though the user clicks the button to push the new view and now the new view is visible to the user to tell the user the video is still playing.

This works fine. I can hear the audio when I go to the new view and I am not releasing my player. However, if I stay on the new view for about 2 minutes and then hit the back button to go to the player view, the audio continues correctly. But the video just fast forwards the frames that have gone by in the 2 minutes and then comes to the current video frame.

Can anyone please suggest why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try addSubView rather than pushing a new view when user clicks on button to go on new view.
I solved my similar problem by this way.